# How to import files to iPhone file system for use in app?

Tags: java, android, ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to develop an iPhone version of an Android app I made. In the Android version you can import spreadsheets to use as templates into the app by copying the file into your sd card from your computer and loading it through an open file dialogue through the app. What would be the a similar way I can do this for non-jailbroken iPhones and iPads to achieve this same functionality?

My goal is to do this without the use of a second app to import them; etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use file sharing. To activate it you have to check UIFileSharingEnabled in your plist file. And you cad drag files to your document directory and out of it via iTunes. You can even specify what data types your app wants to support and you can even register the app to open specific file so if someone, for example send you an email with this file you can press on the file attached and if your app is installed on the device you will be able to use your app to open this file.

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for. I'm new to iOS development coming from Android so it's a little different but I'm sure that I can make a tutorial for people on how to sync it or email it to themselves.

Comment: Start with this: [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1948/itunes-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-integrate-itunes-file-sharing-with-your-ios-app) It's good one.

Comment: Woah, looks a little more complicated than I thought haha! Oh well, how would we progress without challenge, right? :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What are the type of your file ?.

You can use the `UIWebView` to display files with this extensions :

- Excel (.xls)
- Keynote (.key.zip)
- Numbers (.numbers.zip)
- Pages (.pages.zip)
- PDF (.pdf)
- Powerpoint (.ppt)
- Word (.doc)

Where to store your file ?
It depends of your business and your application.

You can store it in a server and the application can load it.
You can store it in the Application sandbox.

For example, you can store it in the application's bundle and use this code to laod your file and display it in a `UIWebView` :

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:documentName ofType:nil];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: Very helpful, thanks! I'm trying to load an excel spreadsheet with very specific patterns to dynamically create the layout for almost every page of the app.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question but have you consider [converting your spreadsheet do a **.csv** file](http://pcunleashed.com/excel/how-to-save-your-excel-spreadsheet-as-a-csv-file/)?

After that you can read your csv and transform it into array.

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://thebigpeeler.wordpress.com/xcode-tutorials/reading-a-csv-file/). It has code that converts a CSV into arrays of the strings in each column / row.

Comment: I can't use csv's as we need a lot of very specific patterns and csv is a little too basic but I do like the idea of this and could possibly fool around with implementing it at some point. Thanks!